# How to center an image on the middle of the page in css?

Tags: css

How can I center something like this right on the middle of the page horizontally?

HTML -

```
 <div class="inner">
<img src="img/shoplove-design.png" alt="Recipe App" />
</div>

CSS
.inner {
width: 800px;          
 }
```

Comment: I tried

display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

But doesnt seem to center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give a width to your img to align horizontally using `margin-left:auto` `margin-right:auto`.

```
 .inner {
   width: 800px;
   border:1px solid black;
 }

 img{
   display:block;
   margin:0 auto;
   width:200px;
 }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xoeusjzc/3/)

Or you can align the img by making it `inline-block` and give a `text-align:center` to its parent

```
 .inner {
   width: 800px;
   border:1px solid black;
   text-align:center;
 }

 img{
   display:inline-block;
 }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ah6fLzua/2/)

Comment: This worked. I haven't specified the width. I set it to 90% and that was perfect placement.

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching a class to your image like

```
<img class="centered" src="img/shoplove-design.png" alt="Recipe App" />
```

and define it like:

```
.centered{width:270px;  /* use yours*/
          height:150px; /* use yours*/
          position:absolute;
          left:50%;
          top:50%;
          margin:-75px 0 0 -135px;} /* use yours divided by 2*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use `text-align: center;` <kbd>[see it in action](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#41e62f6717accf5de31276e651c8a9a7)</kbd>.

This works because <kbd>img</kbd> is a child of <kbd>div.inner</kbd>. Thus <kbd>div.inner</kbd> being that it's a <kbd>div</kbd> element by default it's a <kbd>display: block;</kbd> Thus will have a <kbd>width: 100%;</kbd> of it's parent.

---

Now if you wanted to say align the image vertically as well <kbd>div.inner</kbd> would need to be <kbd>display: table-cell;</kbd> and it's parent would need to be <kbd>display: table;</kbd>.

Then vertically aligning the image is as simple as adding <kbd>vertical-align: middle;</kbd> to <kbd>.inner</kbd>.

[**Example Weave:**](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#fcad28261445fbcae79a9253f502cd2d) http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#fcad28261445fbcae79a9253f502cd2d

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with using a background image, you can also to this:

```
<html><head><style>
html, body {height: 100%}
body {
  background-image: url(img/shoplove-design.png); 
  background-position: center center; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-size: contain;
}
</style></head><body></body></html>
```

This gives the page 100% height and shows the image in the center. To get a better understanding of how the CSS works, I deliberately did not shorten the CSS statements.

A working example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpjZjb?editors=1100

The good thing about this solution is that it is fully responsive and can easily be adjusted to your needs. Here is an example with the div element of the OP: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKPbqX?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question...Use this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Or without table:

```
.center {
    padding: 200px 0;
    text-align: center;
    }
```